# geom_point borders in ggplot2 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the most recent verion of `ggplot2`, a change appears to have been made in the way that `geom_point` is rendered.

For instance, if I attempt to do alpha shading, then I get the following appearance:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, qsec),
            size  = 8,
            stroke = 0,
            alpha = .3)
```

[image]

How can I get `ggplot` to mimic its earlier behavior, and have the points appear without any border?

**Edit:**

As I said, this is occurring in:

> the most recent version of `ggplot2`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.3.0     plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.3      gtable_0.1.2     Rcpp_0.12.2      grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.2
```

**Edit 2**:

These borders also occur in the github version: `ggplot2_2.0.0.9000`

Comment: I have ggplot2_1.0.1 and I don't see any borders

Comment: With `ggplot2` 2.0.0.9000, I can see no borders.

Comment: I've installed new `ggplot2` from `CRAN` today and there exists this problem. @tomw probably meant the newest version.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: I just installed `ggplot2_2.0.0.9000` from CRAN, and I definitely got the borders

Comment: This is interesting. I use Mac OS and can't see the borders. What is your OS?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In an email to the ggplot2 listserve, Hadley mentions "geom_point() now uses shape 19 instead of 16. This looks much better on the default Linux graphics device. (It’s very slightly smaller than the old point, but it shouldn’t affect any graphics significantly)."

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, qsec),
             size  = 8,
             stroke = 0,
             shape=16,
             alpha = .3)
```

[image]

Comment: Also can be found in the latest release notes here: [link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: Interesting modification of a default. Not sure whether it was warranted because old code now needs to be modified with the addition of `shape=16`, which is a filled circle that does _not_ contain a border, unlike `shape=19` which _does_. Imagine trying to convince R core to change the default plotting character from `pch=1` to `pch=20`. They'd all laugh at you.